# What color conversion (or other operation) does imshow perform on this image

Tags: python, opencv

I made a very simple program that reads an image, evaluates the sobel filter and then presents it with imshow.

```
import cv2
img = cv2.imread("/home/alex/imagens/train_5.jpg")

sobelx = cv2.Sobel(img, cv2.CV_64F, 1, 0, ksize=3)  # x
sobely = cv2.Sobel(img, cv2.CV_64F, 0, 1, ksize=3)
norm = cv2.magnitude(sobelx, sobely)

normUint8 = norm.astype('uint8')

cv2.imshow("img", img)
cv2.imshow("norm", norm)
cv2.imshow("normUint8", normUint8)

print "img=" + str(img.dtype) + ", sobel=" + str(norm.dtype) + ", normUint8=" + str(normUint8.dtype)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Here I attach the result.[image]

I expected the result from showing the norm and the normUint8 would be the same or much similar, because their values differ less than 1 at each pixel.
Thus, I believe opencv is performing some operation, before presenting it, when I use an CV_64FC3 image.

I am interested in finding this operation in order to use it.

Can anyone help with it?

Here I attach the original image I used.

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: What version of `opencv` are you using? You are displaying images with `imshow()` using names "img", "norm", and "normUint8" but the results you present have other names (img, sobel and saved_sobel), are you sure they are OK?

Comment: I'm sure. I changed the code and did not changed the image. I'll fix it.

Comment: I'm using the version 2.4.9 from synaptic package on ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Here the correct image corresponding to this code: https://ibb.co/gBiBck

Answer (score 4):

You're feeding a `64FC3` (3 channel, 64bit floats) image to [`imshow`](http://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/d7/dfc/group__highgui.html#ga453d42fe4cb60e5723281a89973ee563). The documentation for this function states:

> The function may scale the image, depending on its depth:
>
> - If the image is 8-bit unsigned, it is displayed as is.
> - If the image is 16-bit unsigned or 32-bit integer, the pixels are divided by 256. That is, the value range [0,255*256] is mapped to [0,255].
> - If the image is 32-bit floating-point, the pixel values are multiplied by 255. That is, the value range [0,1] is mapped to [0,255].

Even though 64-bit floating-point is not mentioned, we can make a decent assumption that they are handled in the same way as 32-bit floats. If we look at the source code, we find out that the conversion is done by function [`cvConvertImage`](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/05b15943d6a42c99e5f921b7dbaa8323f3c042c6/modules/imgcodecs/src/utils.cpp#L592). Specifically, on [line 622](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/05b15943d6a42c99e5f921b7dbaa8323f3c042c6/modules/imgcodecs/src/utils.cpp#L622)

```
double scale = src_depth <= CV_8S ? 1 : src_depth <= CV_32S ? 1./256 : 255;
```

To explain this for those not familiar with the order of the type enums, it's 8U, 8S, 16U, 16S, 32S, 32F, 64F. Hence, bytes get no scaling, other integers division, the rest (floats) multiplication.

Since for display we need an 8bit image, it's important to note that the scaling will be done with saturation (in this case anything over 255 becomes 255, anything below 0 becomes 0).

---

Now that it's clear what kind of transformation `imshow` does, let's have a look at why you see those patches of colour in a sea of white.

Since a simple cast of `norm` to `uint8` gives you an image which is not all black, we can safely assume the values of `norm` are **not** in range `[0.0-1.0]`. When the values are scaled by 255, anything greater or equal to 1.0 will become 255 (white). Due to being a 3 channel image, we can end up with places where only some of the channels are unsaturated, and thus we see various patches of colour.

We can simulate this behaviour by the following script:

```
b,g,r = cv2.split(norm)

r = np.uint8(np.where(r < 1.0, 0, 255))
g = np.uint8(np.where(g < 1.0, 0, 255))
b = np.uint8(np.where(b < 1.0, 0, 255))

cv2.imwrite('sobel_out.png', cv2.merge([b,g,r]))
```

We set pixels to black for values < 1.0, everything else gets white. When we combine the planes, we get the following image:

[image]

Looks familiar?

---

Note: I suspect the square pattern comes from the JPEG compression you used for your input.

Comment: Created a [bug report](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/9010) to fix docs.

Answer (score 2):

Dan's answer is excellent and describes *why* a `float` image can have unintended display properties. Images need a minimum and maximum to know what is black and white, and this isn't always precisely defined for `float` images.

For instance, you could use a `float` image that still has values strictly between 0 and 255 just for calculation precision, to be later rounded to `int` for display. But it's typical in literature to use 0 and 1 as the minimum and maximum, respectively, for image values, as it makes the math that much simpler; and since you need `float` values to represent values between 0 and 1, it's simply common that `float` images use the range 0 to 1. So, OpenCV sticks to this for displaying a `float` image. It *saturates* the image in the range 0 to 1 for a `float`, meaning that it truncates values above and below.

Now if you read in an image, it gets read by default as 8-bit unsigned integers (`CV_U8C3` for a 3-channel image). When you apply the Sobel operator, you specified that you wanted in return a `float` image. This is totally fine, but know that [the Sobel operator is a convolution which multiplies multiple values and sums them up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44081873/what-are-the-units-and-limits-of-gradient-magnitude/44082990#44082990), so this operation *can* give you values larger than what the original image started with. If you used a different return type, then it's possible that these values would get saturated. However, with a float, they won't get saturated until display time. And this is very much on purpose; the Sobel operator can be used on arbitrary matrices, so saturating the values wouldn't always be wanted.

In order to display the image without strange artifacts, you would need to scale the image, either manually like the Stack Overflow answer linked above or by using [`cv2.normalize()`](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html?highlight=normalize#cv2.normalize). Or you can just straight cast to another type like you did, saturating the values at their high end.

Comment: Useful link and suggestion on  how to mitigate the issue, although you kinda skirt answering the actual question. ;) Still you get my thumbs up.

Comment: Yeah I was heading out for lunch, came back to your excellent answer so I didn't bother to edit with more info. You nailed it with the documentation and example, you got my thumbs up earlier :). I'll edit my answer so that it refers to yours and sticks to talking about Sobel for different info.