# Removing Horizontal Lines in image (OpenCV, Python, Matplotlib)

Tags: python, opencv, matplotlib, image-processing, computer-vision

Using the following code I can remove horizontal lines in images. See result below.

```
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

img = cv2.imread('image.png',0)

laplacian = cv2.Laplacian(img,cv2.CV_64F)
sobelx = cv2.Sobel(img,cv2.CV_64F,1,0,ksize=5)

plt.subplot(2,2,1),plt.imshow(img,cmap = 'gray')
plt.title('Original'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
plt.subplot(2,2,2),plt.imshow(laplacian,cmap = 'gray')
plt.title('Laplacian'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
plt.subplot(2,2,3),plt.imshow(sobelx,cmap = 'gray')
plt.title('Sobel X'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])

plt.show()
```

[image: result]

The result is pretty good, not perfect but good. What I want to achieve is the one [showed here](http://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/d1/dee/tutorial_moprh_lines_detection.html).
I am using [this code](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_gradients/py_gradients.html#code).

Source image..
[image: source]

One of my questions is: how to save the `Sobel X` without that grey effect applied ? As original but processed..

Also, is there a better way to do it ?

**EDIT**

Using the following code for the source image is good. Works pretty well.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread("image.png")
img=cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

img = cv2.bitwise_not(img)
th2 = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(img,255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C,cv2.THRESH_BINARY,15,-2)
cv2.imshow("th2", th2)
cv2.imwrite("th2.jpg", th2)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

horizontal = th2
vertical = th2
rows,cols = horizontal.shape

#inverse the image, so that lines are black for masking
horizontal_inv = cv2.bitwise_not(horizontal)
#perform bitwise_and to mask the lines with provided mask
masked_img = cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask=horizontal_inv)
#reverse the image back to normal
masked_img_inv = cv2.bitwise_not(masked_img)
cv2.imshow("masked img", masked_img_inv)
cv2.imwrite("result2.jpg", masked_img_inv)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

horizontalsize = int(cols / 30)
horizontalStructure = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (horizontalsize,1))
horizontal = cv2.erode(horizontal, horizontalStructure, (-1, -1))
horizontal = cv2.dilate(horizontal, horizontalStructure, (-1, -1))
cv2.imshow("horizontal", horizontal)
cv2.imwrite("horizontal.jpg", horizontal)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

verticalsize = int(rows / 30)
verticalStructure = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (1, verticalsize))
vertical = cv2.erode(vertical, verticalStructure, (-1, -1))
vertical = cv2.dilate(vertical, verticalStructure, (-1, -1))
cv2.imshow("vertical", vertical)
cv2.imwrite("vertical.jpg", vertical)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

vertical = cv2.bitwise_not(vertical)
cv2.imshow("vertical_bitwise_not", vertical)
cv2.imwrite("vertical_bitwise_not.jpg", vertical)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

#step1
edges = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(vertical,255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C,cv2.THRESH_BINARY,3,-2)
cv2.imshow("edges", edges)
cv2.imwrite("edges.jpg", edges)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

#step2
kernel = np.ones((2, 2), dtype = "uint8")
dilated = cv2.dilate(edges, kernel)
cv2.imshow("dilated", dilated)
cv2.imwrite("dilated.jpg", dilated)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

# step3
smooth = vertical.copy()

#step 4
smooth = cv2.blur(smooth, (4,4))
cv2.imshow("smooth", smooth)
cv2.imwrite("smooth.jpg", smooth)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

#step 5
(rows, cols) = np.where(img == 0)
vertical[rows, cols] = smooth[rows, cols]

cv2.imshow("vertical_final", vertical)
cv2.imwrite("vertical_final.jpg", vertical)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[image: result]

But if I have this image ?

[image: example]

I tried to execute the code above and the result is really poor...

[image: result3]

Other images which I am working on are these...

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why aren't you using morphological operations like that example shows? This is a perfect use of morphological operations. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44081873/what-are-the-units-and-limits-of-gradient-magnitude/44082990#44082990) for understanding the values coming out of `Sobel`.

Comment: I know, but using the C++ code (event converted to Python) gave me some errors..
If the one I posted above will not work as I want, I will try the morphological operations.
I see you are good at OpenCV, can you give me a hint ? Apart of morph, for now..

Comment: Morphological operations are definitely the best bet here and far easier to use. Gradients will capture edges of the notes which would get deleted along with the lines. Further, Sobel and related functions are general functions which work on any matrix, so they're not strictly made to scale with an image datatype. You could shift, take the absolute value, scale, and threshold the Sobel to binarize it, and use that. Since you're trying to remove horizontal lines, you should use the gradient in the `Y` direction. Notice there's no response of the `X` Sobel on the lines.

Comment: So following [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42461211/how-to-remove-horizontal-and-vertical-lines-from-an-image) should be a good way ?

Comment: What actual image are you trying to do this on? Morphological ops work fine for actual horizontal lines. Are the lines actually horizontal or not? You need to clarify this question a bit with specific examples if you want specific suggestions.

Comment: So, I edited the answer. The lines in the images are actually horizontal. I am adding now other examples..

Comment: Since your lines are present throughout the whole image, using HoughLines would probably be better so that you don't cut off pieces of the text (which would likely happen with morph operations).

Comment: I am looking right now at [the docs](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_houghlines/py_houghlines.html)..

Comment: But there is a way to save the Sobel X image in the first example of code ? Save it without the gray cmap, just as original but with processing ? I want to see how the result is..

Comment: There is no *gray cmap*, the Sobel is the image gradient and the values are the gradient values. There is no such thing as a *original image but with gradient processing*. What you want to do is binarize the sobel image, such that white and black pixels become white and grey pixels become black. Inspect the values of the Sobel image. You can shift it so that gray values are 0, and then you can take the absolute value to make all positive and negative values positive, and scale them to 1 for a `float` or 255 for a `uint8` image. But this is going to remove a lot more than just the lines.

Comment: Usually it's enough just to take the absolute value. See [here](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_gradients/py_gradients.html) for e.g. But notice this is only going to make white the values which are white and black in the sobel image. The gray values will all go black, and that includes the inside of the notes and any horizontal component of all the text. The gradient says "how fast are these pixels changing from white to black" and obviously that happens a lot with text. So looking for high values in the gradients won't correspond only to the line.

Comment: So it's more convenient to use morph or hough..

Comment: You could try both, they should both work well. `HoughLines` would be best for longer lines. `HoughLinesP` could work nicely to *not* remove pieces of text and only the lines but its always hard if not nearly impossible to hone the parameters just right for `HoughLinesP` so I wouldn't bother. Could also try the `LineSegmentDetector`.

Comment: I am using morph code. with the piano notes image it works but with one of my images (last 3) it doesn't...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154688/discussion-between-link-and-alexander-reynolds).

Answer (score 53, accepted):

1. **Obtain binary image.** [Load the image](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-opencv-cv2-imread-method/), convert to [grayscale](https://opencv24-python-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/stable/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_colorspaces/py_colorspaces.html), then [Otsu's threshold](https://opencv24-python-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_thresholding/py_thresholding.html#otsus-binarization) to obtain a binary black/white image.
2. **Detect and remove horizontal lines.** To detect horizontal lines, we create a special [horizontal kernel](https://opencv24-python-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_morphological_ops/py_morphological_ops.html#structuring-element) and [morph open](https://opencv24-python-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_morphological_ops/py_morphological_ops.html#opening) to detect horizontal contours. From here we [find contours](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#findcontours) on the mask and ["fill in"](https://opencv24-python-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_contours/py_contours_begin/py_contours_begin.html)
   the detected horizontal contours with white to effectively remove the lines
3. **Repair image.** At this point the image may have gaps if the horizontal lines intersected through characters. To repair the text, we create a vertical kernel and [morph close](https://opencv24-python-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_morphological_ops/py_morphological_ops.html#closing) to reverse the damage

---

After converting to grayscale, we Otsu's threshold to obtain a binary image

[image]

```
image = cv2.imread('1.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
```

Next we create a special horizontal kernel to detect horizontal lines. We draw these lines onto a mask and then find contours on the mask. To remove the lines, we fill in the contours with white

Detected lines

[image]

Mask

[image]

Filled in contours

[image]

```
# Remove horizontal
horizontal_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (25,1))
detected_lines = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, horizontal_kernel, iterations=2)
cnts = cv2.findContours(detected_lines, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
for c in cnts:
    cv2.drawContours(image, [c], -1, (255,255,255), 2)
```

The image currently has gaps. To fix this, we construct a vertical kernel to repair the image

[image]

```
# Repair image
repair_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (1,6))
result = 255 - cv2.morphologyEx(255 - image, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, repair_kernel, iterations=1)
```

> Note depending on the image, the size of the kernel will change. You can think of the kernel as `(horizontal, vertical)`. For instance, to detect longer lines, we could use a `(50,1)` kernel instead. If we wanted thicker lines, we could increase the 2nd parameter to say `(50,2)`.

Here's the results with the other images

Detected lines

[image]
[image]

Original `->` Removed

[image]
[image]

---

Detected lines

[image]
[image]

Original `->` Removed

[image]
[image]

Full code

```
import cv2

image = cv2.imread('1.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# Remove horizontal
horizontal_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (25,1))
detected_lines = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, horizontal_kernel, iterations=2)
cnts = cv2.findContours(detected_lines, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
for c in cnts:
    cv2.drawContours(image, [c], -1, (255,255,255), 2)

# Repair image
repair_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (1,6))
result = 255 - cv2.morphologyEx(255 - image, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, repair_kernel, iterations=1)

cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.imshow('detected_lines', detected_lines)
cv2.imshow('image', image)
cv2.imshow('result', result)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Comment: Clever. It wouldn't have occurred to me to use two different kernels (with opposing aspect ratios) to open and close.

Comment: how did you get those green 'detected_lines' references. When i run the code, none of the shown images have any green lines?

Comment: @RaduS change the `drawContours` to green color instead of white and save the image. I removed them in this example, it was just for the explanation image.

Comment: @Ajinkya switch to a vertical kernel instead of a horizontal kernel, see my previous answers for an example

Comment: @nathancy can't we replace the `findContours/drawContours` part with just `cv2.bitwise_or(image, detected_lines)`?

Comment: @Glider yes you could but I used the `findContours` and `drawContours` to highlight the green lines. Both methods would work

Comment: How to explain `cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]` when you apply binary inversion plus otsu threshold? And what does `[1]` means at the end?

Comment: `cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]` what this check is about, can you please explain, @nuthancy ?

Comment: @nathancy can you suggest any method to remove 'doted lines' in the image, please