# Remove small vertical lines in between the character from an image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I want to remove all horizontal and vertical lines. I am able to remove horizontal lines, but while removing small vertical lines the original text is also getting impacted. This is the code I'm using:

```
image = cv2.imread('opt/doc/uploads/img1.png')
result = image.copy()
blur = image.copy()
gray = cv2.cvtColor(blur,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0,255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

rows,cols = thresh.shape
horizontalsize = int(cols // 30)
verticalsize = int(rows // 30)

# Remove horizontal lines
horizontal_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (horizontalsize,1))
remove_horizontal = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, horizontal_kernel)
cnts = cv2.findContours(remove_horizontal, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
for c in cnts:
    cv2.drawContours(result, [c], -1, (255,255,255), 3)                        


# Remove vertical lines
vertical_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (1,20))        
remove_vertical = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, vertical_kernel)
cnts = cv2.findContours(remove_vertical, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
for c in cnts:
    cv2.drawContours(result, [c], -1, (255,255,255),3)

cv2.imwrite('result.png', result)
```

PFB 2 the input image:

[image: Input Image]
[image: Input Image]

PFB output Image of above 2 images respectively:

[image: Output]
[image: output]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing Horizontal Lines in image (OpenCV, Python, Matplotlib)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46274961/removing-horizontal-lines-in-image-opencv-python-matplotlib)

Comment: Hi Sachin i am having problem while removing small vertical lines. whenever i am trying to remove the small vertical lines the original text is also getting impacted, there is no issue while removing horizontal lines.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to detect horizontal/vertical lines, another approach is to filter using contour area to "ignore" the lines and just take the desired text characters. One limitation is it will not detect text that is connected to the horizontal/vertical lines

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

image = cv2.imread('1.png')
mask = np.ones(image.shape, dtype=np.uint8) * 255
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
for c in cnts:
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    if area < 1000:
        x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
        mask[y:y+h, x:x+w] = image[y:y+h, x:x+w]

cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.imshow('mask', mask)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Comment: Hi @nathancy  your solution is working fine if there is horizontal line but in some scenarios i will have images which will have only vertical lines no horizontal. then how i can remove those vertical lines. can you please help.

Comment: You can create a special vertical kernel to remove the lines, another filter would be to filter using contour area

Comment: I have already tried with vertical kernel to remove vertical lines but in that approach it also tampers the character (it removes the vertical lines from character too) like D,F,H,I,M etc which has vertical lines (PFA image above).                                                             And if i use contour area filter for vertical lines then it also remove the character whose contour area less than the vertical line or same as vertical line.

Comment: Try using morphological operations such as `cv2.MORPH_CLOSE` to fill in the broken characters