# Extract handwritten characters from a boxed form field image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, image-segmentation

I am trying to extract handwritten characters from field boxes

[image]

My desired output would be the character segments with the boxes removed. So far, I've tried defining contours and filtering by area but that hasn't yielded any good results.

```
# Reading image and binarization
im = cv2.imread('test.png')

char_gray = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
char_bw = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(char_gray, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 75, 10)

# Applying erosion and dilation
kernel = np.ones((5,5), np.uint8) 
img_erosion = cv2.erode(char_bw, kernel, iterations=1)
img_dilation = cv2.dilate(img_erosion, kernel, iterations=1)  

# Find Canny edges 
edged = cv2.Canny(img_dilation, 100, 200) 

# Finding Contours 
edged_copy = edged.copy()
im2, cnts, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(edged_copy, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
print("Number of Contours found = " + str(len(cnts))) 

# Draw all contours 
cv2.drawContours(im, cnts, -1, (0, 255, 0), 3)

# Filter using area and save
for no, c in enumerate(cnts):
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    if area > 100:
        contour = c
        (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
        img = im[y:y+h, x:x+w]
        cv2.imwrite(f'./cnts/cnt-{no}.png', img_dilation)
```

Comment: Please do some research on your problem before asking on this forum. Search this forum and Google for your type of problem. A search of Google shows: https://medium.com/coinmonks/a-box-detection-algorithm-for-any-image-containing-boxes-756c15d7ed26 and https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/07/10/using-tesseract-ocr-python/

Comment: You can try [removing horizontal and vertical lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46274961/removing-horizontal-lines-in-image-opencv-python-matplotlib) as a preprocessing step before extracting the characters

Comment: @fmw42 Hi, I've tried that approach before but it fails to detect any ROIs on my images.

Comment: I gave it a shot with @coffeewin idea, but it doesn't seem to completely remove the lines, thus decreasing ocr accuracy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simple approach:

1. **Obtain binary image.** We load the image, enlarge using `imutils.resize()`, convert to grayscale, and perform Otsu's thresholding to obtain a binary image
2. **Remove horizontal lines.** We create a horizontal kernel then perform morphological opening and remove the horizontal lines using `cv2.drawContours`
3. **Remove vertical lines.** We create a vertical kernel then perform morphological opening and remove the vertical lines using `cv2.drawContours`

---

Here's a visualization of each step:

Binary image

[image]

Detected lines/boxes to remove highlighted in green

[image]

Result

[image]

Code

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import imutils

# Load image, enlarge, convert to grayscale, Otsu's threshold
image = cv2.imread('1.png')
image = imutils.resize(image, width=500)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# Remove horizontal
horizontal_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (25,1))
detect_horizontal = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, horizontal_kernel, iterations=2)
cnts = cv2.findContours(detect_horizontal, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
for c in cnts:
    cv2.drawContours(image, [c], -1, (255,255,255), 5)

# Remove vertical
vertical_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (1,25))
detect_vertical = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, vertical_kernel, iterations=2)
cnts = cv2.findContours(detect_vertical, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
for c in cnts:
    cv2.drawContours(image, [c], -1, (255,255,255), 5)

cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.imshow('image', image)
cv2.waitKey()
```