# OpenCV - Remove black lines stick to text

Tags: python, opencv, tesseract

In some files I have black lines that stick to the text I need to retrieve with Tesseract. Is there any magic to do with OpenCV ?

Any examples where Tesseract return me nothing :

[image]
[image]
[image]

Any ideas, solutions to dig ?

Thanks

Comment: Here is a similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46274961/removing-horizontal-lines-in-image-opencv-python-matplotlib

Comment: I think it may help you

Comment: I'll check, thanks a lot :)

Comment: Check each row and column, if black pixel value continuosly, it means that column or row is a line. Then delete those rows and xolumns