# Remove specific horizontal lines in table

Tags: python, opencv

I am searching everywhere with regards to Python Open CV. Is there a way to remove specific horizontal lines from the given image below? I tried this method [remove lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46274961/removing-horizontal-lines-in-image-opencv-python-matplotlib) but it seems to remove all horizontal lines.

Original image:

[image: Original image]

Desire image:

[image: Desire image]

Comment: You could remove the long horizontal lines with a long kernel and the vertical lines. Then get the difference to find the short horizontal lines. Then subtract those from the input.

Answer (score 2):

Check if this helps

```
import cv2

# Load image, convert to grayscale. Choosen Otsu's method for automatic image thresholding.
image = cv2.imread('Kw2gB.png')
result = image.copy()
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
# Detect horizontal lines
horizontal_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (80,1))
detect_horizontal = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, horizontal_kernel, iterations=2)
cnts = cv2.findContours(detect_horizontal, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
for c in cnts:
    cv2.drawContours(result, [c], -1, (36,255,12), 2)

# Detect vertical lines
vertical_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (1,10))
detect_vertical = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, vertical_kernel, iterations=2)
cnts = cv2.findContours(detect_vertical, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
for c in cnts:
    cv2.drawContours(result, [c], -1, (36,255,12), 2)

cv2.imshow('result', image-result)
cv2.waitKey()
```

[image]