# Infill image gaps after Morph Open opencv

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I have an input signature for which I want to remove the gridlines of same color.
[image]

So far I am using this [python code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58002605/3592342) to do that

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

## Load image and make B&W version
image = cv2.imread('Downloads/image.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# Remove horizontal
horizontal_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (50,1))
detected_lines = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, horizontal_kernel, iterations=2)
cnts = cv2.findContours(detected_lines, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
for c in cnts:
    cv2.drawContours(thresh, [c], -1, (0,0,0), 2)

cv2.imwrite('Downloads/out.png', thresh)
```

Which takes me to the following image.

[image]

Now I am trying to infill the gaps introduced, I tried using a vertical kernel and morph close but that infills the other spaces in images a lot.

Any ideas on how I can achieve the said infilling using a more sophisticated operation and get the infill done without tampering with the existing signature much.

Comment: A simple trick is to replace the line by the content of a thin rectangle just above or below.

Comment: That would be helpful if all the lines were vertical, But as you can see in the signature above, some lines are at an angle to the gridline being removed so replacing the line with the content just above or below wouldn't make the remaining lines fully connected.
I think I need some solution which can detect the lines and infill where the continuity is broken by a little.

Comment: I said a simple trick. :)

Comment: Am I right to think that this is just a sketch that you made for the sake of illustration ? If true, post real scans.

Comment: Its a demo image made by taking an signature image from google, But the image is a true representative of the original data. The original images are indeed of same color and cropped in similar manner.

Comment: try morphology close with a kernel large enough to fill the gaps

Comment: Tried with a vertical kernel large enough, But in most of the signatures it tends to fill the loops within characters and make the final image noisy for further analysis.